# How to make my .selected class stay on the correct a(href) after the reload in a list of hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug, href

I have a sidebar of links that loads everytime you click on a link, however when I load the next page, the .selected class moves back to "all" instead of the selected link.

I know this is explained with tabs on here but I could not make it work using the methods I found with my list instead of tabs

I am using javascript to compile the list of links, jade for display.

Jade Code(Kinda, I deleted the unnecessary stuff)

```
        ul.new.category
          li.selected
            div
              a.anm_det_pop(href='/popular')
                strong All
          each i in list
            li
              div
                a.anm_det_pop(href='/page/#{i}')
                  strong #{i.toUpperCase()}
```

My Script

```
script.
$(function(){
  $('.category > li').click(function(){
    $('.category > li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

The script works to the point where I click it I briefly see the class switch before the reload, after the reload the .selected class goes back to all.

What I would like to accomplish is the .selected class staying on the active link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think something else is happening on your page. Do you have something we can view online?

Comment: None of this is live yet, only local host

Comment: If you remove your script, is the `.selected` class being added to all list items?

Comment: No, It would stay with the li. selected  blah blah strong ALL in the list, the first item

Comment: Can you copy the output of the jade code with script and place in jsfiddle?

Comment: About to leave and I would have to convert jade to html

Comment: Actually give me one sec

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0bk8aamu/ somethin like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, for those with the same question, I moved the whole function into a mixin, I had already made the function in js with sequilize to include the current page as well as the list for my href list so it was relatively simple.

```
mixin List(List,currentPage)
  ul.new.category
    li(class=!currentPage ? 'selected' : '')
      div
        a.anm_det_pop(href='/popular')
          strong All
    each i in list
      li(class=currentPage === i.page ? 'selected' : '')
        div
          a.anm_det_pop(href='/genre/#{i.page}')
            strong #{toTitleCase(i)}
```

Than in the Jade you just add the mixin and than add the list as a param

```
+List(List,currentPage)
```

The mixin reads the current page and compares it to the list, than makes that selection in the list have the class .selection.

Perfect for what I needed.

Hope this helps someone else out as I spent a day tryin to figure out something that took me 15 minutes to do

Answer (score 0):

Given I'm not entirely sure how the page is working, I think you need to prevent the default click event. Hope this doesn't break the application.

```
$(function(){
  $('.category > li').click(function(e){
    $('.category > li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: That actually cancelled the .selected because it prevents default